# How to display blank field in some columns in editform (infopath)?

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, button

I have a form and a button with some rules , what the button is doing is its submitting the data refreshing the page and openeing editform in the page with all those details submitted. But i want few columns to come blank and shouldnt display anything on the edit form but the data will be there in the list as previously it will submit.

Comment: You can use "Set a field's value" action on "Form Load" but the problem is after saving the edit form the blank value will be get saved. So, as a workaround, you can hide the control.

Comment: Ya that can be done even if the columns appeared to be filled can be removed and filled with new data again and saved . But as a requirement is there any possibility to display blank columns?